# Setup Windows 7 Virtualbox notifications in host Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

Is there any way to setup notification (such as a message from Skype or Lync) coming in the Windows OS running inside a Virtual Box to be notified in host Ubuntu (At least something like highlighting Virtual box icon or something like that).

Comment: Not really, at least without serious amounts of hacking. You could write a windows program that detect that activity and sends a warning to a Linux program through the network or other method.